# Is there a hidden meaning in the name of Captain Foulenough?

Tags: translation, name-significance, evelyn-waugh, brideshead-revisited

The novel *Brideshead Revisited* features a secondary character, a certain Captain Foulenough. In Russian translation his last name is rendered as Буремглой, obviously referring to a Pushkin's line

> Буря мглою небо кроет
>
> (The storm covers sky with darkness)

It is a famous poem, known by every Russian fourth-grader.

The search for *foul enough* in a similar context yields [An Island](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/a/amverse/BAD9522.0001.001/1:6?rgn=div1;view=fulltext), by Edwin Arlington Robinson:

> a storm foul enough

I trust the translator; I am sure she came up with such rendering for a reason. On the other hand, I doubt that Robinson was known in 1945 England as much as Pushkin in Russia.

The question is, did Waugh intentionally attach a hidden meaning, and did he expect this hidden meaning to be understood by an average reader?

Comment: *Foul enough* is perfectly meaningful in English, even without considering the Edwin Arlington Robinson poem.

Comment: @PeterShor _storm_ is very important here, otherwise a direct translation would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Waugh seems to have borrowed the character *Captain Foulenough* from a [long-running newspaper column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beachcomber_(pen_name)) published under the pen name Beachcomber. So if *Captain Foulenough* is a reference to Edwin Arlington Robinson's poem *An Island*, it would not have been Evelyn Waugh's reference.

And it seems very unlikely that it is a reference to *An Island*. Edwin Arlington Robinson wrote a handful of poems that are quite well-known ([Richard Cory](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44982/richard-cory) and [Mr. Flood's Party](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44979/mr-floods-party) being among the most famous), but as far as I know, *An Island* was never one of his better known poems. And naming an "archetypical cad and gatecrasher" after a line in a poem about Napoleon seems rather bizarre.